# Prove that there exist closed sets $F_1,F_2$ with $F=F_1 \cup F_2$, $F_1 \subseteq U_1$, and $F_2 \subseteq U_2$ (by contradiction)

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

This problem comes from  [Question on Normal Topological Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146350/question-on-normal-topological-spaces).

I was wondering if this can be done by contradiction.

> Problem.  Suppose that $X$ is a normal topological space, that $F\subseteq X$ is closed, and that $F\subseteq U_1 \cup U_2$ for open sets $U_1,U_2$. Prove that there exist closed sets $F_1,F_2$ with $F=F_1 \cup F_2$, $F_1 \subseteq U_1$, and $F_2 \subseteq U_2.$

Attempt.

Since X is normal, then for every $F_1,F_2$ closed with $F_1\cap F_2=\varnothing$, there exists $U_1,U_2$ open, so that $F_1\subset U_1, F_2\subset U_2 $ and $U_1\cap U_2=\varnothing.$

One needs to prove that for all $F_1,F_2$ closed, $F\neq F_1 \cup F_2$, $F_1 \not\subseteq U_1$, or $F_2 \not \subseteq U_2...[1]$

---

One idea, I think, but I'm  not sure if it's correct:

Let $F_1,F_2$ be closed.

Let $x\in F.$ Since $F\neq F_1 \cup F_2,$ then 1) $F\not\subset (F_1 \cup F_2)$ or 2) $ (F_1 \cup F_2)\not\subset F.$

Suppose 1), then $F_1\cap F_2=\varnothing.$ Thus one can apply normality i.e. there exists $U_1,U_2$ open, so that $F_1\subset U_1, F_2\subset U_2 $ and $U_1\cap U_2=\varnothing.$

But with this, there'd be a contradiction e.g. with one assumption $F_1 \not\subseteq U_1$...(1)

---

Is that correct?

A no no, (1) is not correct because there's an *or* in [1], so at least 2 of them  could indeed be false.. sorry, I just noticed about this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the closed sets $F\setminus U_1$ and $F\setminus U_2$. Check that these are disjoint. By normality there exest open sets $V_1,V_2$ such that $V_1\cap V_2=\emptyset$ and $F\setminus U_1 \subset V_1$,$F\setminus U_2 \subset V_2$. Now show that $F_1=F\setminus V_1$ and $F_2=F\setminus V_2$ satsifies your requirements.